# Excel multiple If(Isnumber (search)

Tags: excel, if-statement, search

Can you do multiple =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH)) in Excel?  I would like a single formula to look at several text strings and give a result if one of various words are in that string.

For example if I had below items on the left - I would want an equation to give the results on the right.  I used =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*1pc*",A1)),"1 Pc","") and it pulled the 1 Pc I was looking for but how do I pull the other items like 2 Pc or Set?

```
Floral 1pc                         1 Pc
Floral 1pc                         1 Pc
1pc w/bow                          1 Pc
Pink Heart  Set                        Set
Pink Heart  Set                        Set
Multi Mini Heart 2pc w/bow         2 Pc
Multi Mini Heart 2pc w/bow         2 Pc
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with what to be searched and what to return:

[image]

Then you can us the following array formula:

```
=INDEX($F$1:$F$3,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$1:$E$3,A1)),0))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]